# Who is responsible for data sanitization in WordPress development?

Tags: database, security, customization, validation, sanitization

I am studying how to write more secure WordPress code by implementing validation, sanitization and data escaping wherever necessary. Validation and escaping makes perfect sense, but I am a little confused about sanitization.

If I use a function like `add_post_meta`, does this function do sanitization for me? What about `set_option` or other ones that interact with the database. I usually interact with the database via these functions. In which situations do I need to worry about sanitization myself?

Comment: You're talking about SQL sanitising correct?

Comment: Yes, preparing data to be stored inside the database.

Comment: This should answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122790/sql-safety-when-storing-data-using-wordpress-built-in-functions

Comment: Thank you! I'm going through several articles on this topics right now and most of them use code examples that validate and sanitize input before passing it to one of these functions. Does that mean that is unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, WordPress will sanitise data on its way to the database, so long as you use the APIs.

If you're using the `wpdb` object however you'll need to use the `prepare` method to sanitise. I recommend against writing SQL queries as it bypasses object caches etc, but if you must write your own SQL, use `wpdb` to prepare and execute it

For calls such as `WP_Query`, `get_posts`, `add_post_meta` etc etc sanitisation occurs

Note that this is purely DB sanitisation, any additional sanitisation or validation you require, such as trimming trailing spaces, validation of URLs, stripping tags, escaping, etc, must all be done in your code

Comment: @MauroBringolf great :) if you could mark it as the correct answer?